# Ruby: multidimensional array to one-dimensional rows

Tags: arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array

In Ruby, how do I go from this:

```
[
  1, 
  ["green", "blue", "black"], 
  [ ["1", "2"], ["3"], ["4", "5"] ]
]
```

to this?

```
[
  [1, "green", "1"],
  [1, "green", "2"],
  [1, "blue", "3"],
  [1, "black", "4"],
  [1, "black", "5"],
]
```

I tried .zip but with no luck. Any help is greatly appreciated, and of course I'm looking for a performant solution.

Comment: When you given an example it's helpful to assign a variable to each input object (e.g., `arr = [1, ["green", "blue", "black"], [ ["1", "2"], ["3"], ["4", "5"] ]]`. That way, readers can refer to the variables in answers and comments without having define them, and all readers will use the same variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed a more generic and flexible solution as compared to the ones proposed (my bad, I should have been more clear about the requirements), so I came up with the following:

```
class Array
  def transpose_rows
    arys = self.select{|el| el.is_a?(Array)}
    if arys.size == 0
      [self]
    else 
      result = []
      (arys.map(&:size).max || 1).times.map{ |i|
        self.map { |r| 
          r.is_a?(Array) ? r[i] : r
        }.transpose_rows.map{|r| result << r}
      }
      result
    end
  end
end
```

The initial spec is that every element in the array is either a value or another array of varying depth. Each subarray "explodes" the values of the subarrays of *depth-1* into an arbitrary number of "sub-values". The result should be a set of rows listing all combinations deriving from the original array.

The other solutions proposed do work for the original array I posted, which was just an example, while this one works for more complex scenarios such as the following:

```
[
  2, 
  [3,4,5], 
  6, 
  [7,8,9], 
  [ [11,22], [33], [44,55] ], 
  [0, 1, 2],
  [ [66], [77], [nil,99] ],
  4
].transpose_rows

# => [
#   [2, 3, 6, 7, 11, 0, 66, 4], 
#   [2, 3, 6, 7, 22, 0, nil, 4], 
#   [2, 4, 6, 8, 33, 1, 77, 4], 
#   [2, 5, 6, 9, 44, 2, nil, 4], 
#   [2, 5, 6, 9, 55, 2, 99, 4]
# ]
```

Answer (score 3):

The pattern is not completely clear to me, but this gets the expected output for the example you provided:

```
data[1].
  zip(data[2]).
  flat_map { |x, ys| [x].product(ys) }.
  map { |zs| [data[0], *zs] }
#=> [[1, "green", "1"], [1, "green", "2"], [1, "blue", "3"], 
#    [1, "black", "4"], [1, "black", "5"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

We are given

```
arr = [1, ["green", "blue", "black"], [ ["1", "2"], ["3"], ["4", "5"] ]]
```

Here are a couple of ways to obtain the desired result.

**#1**

```
arr[1].flat_map.with_index { |color,i| [arr[0]].product([color], arr[2][i]) }
  #=> [[1, "green", "1"], [1, "green", "2"], [1, "blue", "3"],
  #    [1, "black", "4"], [1, "black", "5"]]
```

The steps are as follows.

```
enum0 = arr[1].flat_map
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["green", "blue", "black"]:flat_map>
enum1 = enum0.with_index
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: ["green", "blue", "black"]:flat_map>:with_index>
```

`enum1` can be thought of as a *compound enumerator*. We can see the values that will be generated by `enum1` and passed to the block by converting it to an array.

```
enum1.to_a
  #=> [["green", 0], ["blue", 1], ["black", 2]]
```

The first value is generated and passed to the block, the block variables are assigned and the block calculation is performed.

```
color, i = enum1.next
  #=> ["green", 0]
color
  #=> "green"
i #=> 0
[arr[0]].product([color], arr[2][i])
  #=> [1].product(["green"], )
  #=> [[1, "green", "1"], [1, "green", "2"]]
```

The calculations are similar for the two remaining elements generated by `enum1`.

An alternative to this is to dup `arr[2]` and shift elements of the dup:

```
a2 = arr[2].dup
arr[1].flat_map { |color,i| [arr[0]].product([color], a2.shift) }
```

**#2**

```
arr[1].zip(arr[2]).flat_map { |color, a| [arr[0]].product([color], a) }
  #=> [[1, "green", "1"], [1, "green", "2"], [1, "blue", "3"],
  #    [1, "black", "4"], [1, "black", "5"]]
```

The steps are as follows.

```
b = arr[1].zip(arr[2])
  #=> [["green", ["1", "2"]], ["blue", ["3"]], ["black", ["4", "5"]]]
```

`b[0]` is passed to `flat_map` and the block variables are assigned and the block calculation is performed.

```
color, a = b[0]
  #=> ["green", ["1", "2"]]
color
  #=> "green"
a #=> ["1", "2"]
[arr[0]].product([color], a)
  #=> [["1"]].product(["green"], ["1", "2"])
  #=>  [[1, "green", "1"], [1, "green", "2"]]
```

After the remaining elements of `b` are passed to `map` the desired array is returned by [Enumerable#flat_map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map).

Comment: Thanks, @tokland. As a `flat_map` believer, I should have seen that. I edited.